# Stripe webhook events: find out origin of event

Tags: java, spring, stripe-payments

When using the stripe dashboard, one can clearly see where an event is originating from (e.g. automatic, dashboard, API). We would like to be able to do this in our spring (java) backend implementation as well.

Here is how we receive the events in our server:

```
@EventListener
@Async
public void handleStripeWebhook(StripeWebhookEvent stripeWebhookEvent) throws EntityNotFoundException, StripeException {
   final var event = stripeWebhookEvent.event();
   final var stripeObject = stripeWebhookEvent.stripeObject();

   Invoice invoice;
   Subscription subscription;
   switch (event.getType()) {
      case "invoice.created":
      // ...
   }
}
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Event.request.id` (which I assume to be exposed via some getters in the library you're using) and see whether it is null. If it is, the event was triggered automatically, else it was via the API (or Dashboard I'd assume) and you can get more details about the request via its ID.

The Stripe Documentation says this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-request-id).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not distinguish all cases correctly. I think there really is no solution to my question.